# How to measure browser boot time + page load time

Tags: c#, page-load-time, load-time

There are a lot of tools to measure webpage load time but my goal is not  to measure just server, network and rendering speed but overall user experience from the clicking a link to getting page ready (PC Windows).

I have some experience in C# but can't wrap my mind how to get started. Would you head me please?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/performance

Comment: I don't think I really need such level of performance details. Would be great to have just feedback from the browser that the page load is complete, so I can start a browser and measure time from the start to page competition. The question, how to get know that the page is loaded completely? Any idea?